# dvipdf creates 2MB PDF on one machine, 7MB PDF on another

Tags: installing, dvipdf

First - I don't know anything about TeX itself, I'm just trying to get other people's .tex file to work.

I'm trying to get the following to work (from looking at the Makefile):

- A process creates a `.tex` file
- `latex` is run to create a `.dvi` file
- The `.dvi` file is sent to `dvipdf` to create a `.pdf` file

This should produce a 2.2MB file, much like [this one](http://dlang.org/dlangspec.pdf).

Instead, I get [this file](http://dlang.k3.1azy.net/dlangspec.pdf). Apparently there is some difference in my setup, because my output is 7MB instead of 2, and also renders much slower in Firefox, for some reason.

This is an Ubuntu Server 14.04 machine. I installed LaTeX by installing the packages `texlive`, `texlive-latex-extra`, and `texlive-fonts-extra`.

Also, I'm fairly sure this is not normal, the `dvipdf` step takes about half an hour to run.

The generated `.tex` files are identical on both machines, and the `.dvi` file differs in only a few bytes (some timestamp, I assume). You can get them [here](http://dlang.k3.1azy.net/dlangspec.tex) and [here](http://dlang.k3.1azy.net/dlangspec.dvi).

What do I need to change in my setup or build process to get an output more like the 2MB file?

Comment: Is it possible that on one of the machines, a font was missing and so one of the machines had to make font substitutions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, we tried running `pdflatex` instead, and now it runs quickly and produces a 1.3MB file (even smaller than the original). I guess this will do.